# Alternative proof of Cauchy Schwarz Inequality implication

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Cauchy Schwarz inequality says that if $x,y\neq0$ there will be equality, that is, $|x||y|=\|x\|\|y\|$ iff  for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$x=cy$$

(that is $x$ is parallel to $y$)

Now,
Starting from $x=cy$ and proving equality is trivial. I want you guys to see if the otherf way round is mathematically sound or not.

Given,
$$|x\cdot y|=\|x\|\|y\|$$
To prove $$\exists \, c\in \mathbb{R} : x=cy $$

Now,
**Case I:** $x\cdot y \gt 0$

Consider $$z=y-tx$$
Clearly,
$$z \cdot z \ge 0$$
That is,
$$p(t)=(y-tx)\cdot (y-tx)\ge 0$$
$$p(t)=\|y\|^2  - 2t(x\cdot y)+t^2 \|x\|^2 \ge 0$$
$$\Rightarrow p(t)=\|y\|^2  - 2t\|x\|\|y\|+t^2 \|x\|^2\ge 0$$
Clearly,
$$p\left(\frac {\|y\|}{\|x\|}\right)=0$$
Since equality of the dot product of the vector with itself to zero implies the vector must itself be zero
$$\therefore y-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}x=0$$
$$\therefore y=\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}x$$

**Case II:** $x\cdot y\lt 0$
We consider $z'= (y + sx)$ and the rest is similar.
In either case y is a scalar multiple of x.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. For scalar product we have $a\cdot b=0\iff a\perp b$, so $(a=0)\lor(b=0)$ doesn't follow.

Comment: you should assume $x \neq 0$ in order to divide by $(x\cdot x)$

Comment: @Berci -How about now

Comment: Now this seems fine.

Comment: @KaranKumar Looks good now, though there's no real need to break into cases, just use $x \cdot y = \pm \|x\| \|y\|$ (and your $z'$ has a typo anyway). For what it's worth, I like [Terry Tao's explanation](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/amplification-arbitrage-and-the-tensor-power-trick/) of this argument.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson fixed the typo. Thanks. Checked Terrence Tao's page. Difficult to understand as I am just a newbie and he is the Stephen Hawking of modern math himself 